Windows "winget" says that a program is installed but it is not anywhere on the installation drive
I had downloaded and installed clink manually. It did not show up anywhere on the path. So then I used the package installer: it says that it is already installed:
C:\Users\sboesch>winget install clink

Found an existing package already installed. Trying to upgrade the installed package...
No available upgrade found.
No newer package versions are available from the configured sources.

But it still does not show up:
C:\Users\sboesch>clink
'clink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sboesch>where clink.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Here's the path:
C:\Users\sboesch>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

Is it anywhere on the installation drive?
C:\>dir /s clink.exe
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is B22C-F287
File Not Found

So then where is this installed? And why does not it not show up anywhere / take effect on the path?
Update clink does show up in the All apps:

Another update
I did winget uninstall clink and winget install clink again. Still does not show up
C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local>winget uninstall clink
Found Clink [chrisant996.Clink]
Starting package uninstall...
Successfully uninstalled

C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local>winget install clink
Found Clink [chrisant996.Clink] Version 1.6.14
This application is licensed to you by its owner.
Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages.
Downloading https://github.com/chrisant996/clink/releases/download/v1.6.14/clink.1.6.14.93b83f_setup.exe
  ██████████████████████████████  2.34 MB / 2.34 MB
Successfully verified installer hash
Starting package install...
Successfully installed

C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local>where clink
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local>where clink.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\sboesch\AppData\Local>clink
'clink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Try to check in this location: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\.

@ReddyLutonadio  underneath %LOCALAPPDATA there is a directory clink. So maybe windows is confused by an unsuccessful previous install. I will try deleting that dir and do winget install again. In any case winget install should have done more work than just seeing if the directory were there!

Winget looks at whatever the package itself tells it to. Are you sure the package isn't installed and not just missing from %PATH%? Is it even supposed to be in %PATH% in the first place?

So what's happening is the clink installation does create the clink directory but NO FILES are copied there.  I wonder if there is a problem with compatibility with the version of windows and clink..

It appears that the program were installed successfully. My confusion was about how the program clink actually works. It does not show up anywhere in normal command prompts: but only when launching clink program from the Start menu. It is a strange program.


I installed clink and couldn't find clink.exe. Why? Because it doesn't exist. Searching my drive for files that have clink has pert of their names, I get 4 files:

clink.bat
clink_x64.exe
clink_x86.exe
clink_unistall_1.6.14.93b83f.exe

The real executables depending on your PC's architecture are clink_x64.exe and clink_x86.exe. clink.bat is the tool that launches either one of them. The fourth file is the uninstaller.
On the start menu, the clink shortcut leads to clink.bat. All of them are installed IN C:\Program Files (x86)\clink folder.

